# Usecase inside a custom view

Tags: android, android-studio, mvvm, viewmodel

First of all, sorry for my english, this is google translator.

I am learning mvvm, maybe I have some misconception but I think I can understand it well.

My goal is to load an image in an imageview, but the final path of the image is built with the width of the imageview

```
GET /images
    "images": {
        "avatar": [64, 128],
        "xxxxxx": [512, 640, 1024]
    }
```

```
GET /user/1234567
    "user": {
        "username": "john",
        "avatar": "123123.png"
    }
```

Now if I want to display john's avatar in a 64px image the final path would be:

```
myserver.com/images/64/123123.png
```

If on the other hand, the size of the imageview is 600px I would use:

```
myserver.com/images/128/123123.png
```

To do this I have created a customview that extends an imageview and I use a usecase

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyImageView(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
) : ImageView(context, attrs) {
   
    @Inject
    lateinit var pictureUseCase: PictureUseCase
    
    fun build(type: Picture.Type, endpoint: String) {
        val type = when (type) {
            0 -> Picture.Type.AVATAR
            1 -> Picture.Type.XXXXXX 
            else -> throw Exception("unexpected")
        }
        val base = pictureUseCase(type, measuredWidth)
        
        val awesomeurl = base + endpoint // Here i have the final url
        // Picasso...
    }
    
}
```

This code generates an error without importance in the execution of the app but it breaks the preview of the view

```
_layoutlib_._internal_.kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property pictureUseCase has not been initialized
```

- Is there an annotation to disable it in the preview?
- Can I use a viewmodel inside a view?
- Would there be a problem if I use this customview + viewmodel inside an adapter with hundreds of elements?